# Killing terminal before running task

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have defined two tasks in VS code (flash, monitor) that uses same COM port.

I would like to automaticaly kill monitor task (terminal), before running flash task. 
How can I do this ?

Regards, 
Boris Makovecki

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's possible, but you might be able to run them both in same terminal using `make flash monitor`?